# Select row minimum col for each id

Tags: sql

I have a table like following

```
id    id_a    id_b    uds
--------------------------
1      1        3      20
1      2        8      17
2      1        3       5
3      1        1      32
3      2        1       6
```

What I would need is to get the row with minimum "uds" for each "id". So the result would be:

```
id    id_a    id_b    uds
--------------------------
1      2        8      17
2      1        3       5
3      2        1       6
```

Thank you in advance...

Comment: It better to share what you've attempted first, then SO's can advise what you doing wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most databases support the ANSI standard window functions.  An easy way to do what you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by uds) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Min` with a `group by` clause:

```
select id, id_a, id_b, min(uds) as uds 
from table1 
group by id, id_a, id_b
order by id, id_a, id_b;
```

However, I should mention this is going to get you all of the items, you need to also specify an aggregate on the other columns, or do not include them.

```
select id, min(uds) as uds 
from table1 
group by id
order by id;
```

Judging by your desired output though, the following may be what you want:

```
select id, max(id_a) as id_a, max(id_b) as id_b, min(uds) as uds 
from table1 
group by id
order by id;
```

Comment: this would return 2 rows for id = 1. 1 row is expected.

Comment: Updated as you were commenting to take that into account.

Comment: what about returning the row(s) with min uds, including id_a, id_b.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set condition with minimum uds value or you have to decides how many numbers of records you want with minimum uds

Answer (score 0):

More one way:

```
select 
    a.*
from 
    #temp a inner join (select id, min(uds) minUds from #temp group by id) b on 
        a.id = b.id 
        and a.uds = b.minUds
```